# python scipy.stats.binomtest pvalue gives unexpected ratio in randomized tests

Tags: scipy, statistics

When conducting an experiment, the `p value` is the chance that the experiment's result was obtained by chance given the null hypothesis.

I wrote a few lines of code to check if `scipy.stats.binomtest` gives this result. Each experiment executes 20 bets with 0.1 chance of success for each. I ran 20,000 experiments, and found the the percentage of those with `p value < 0.02` was not 0.02 but closer to 0.011.
Is this a problem with the python library, or am I missing some statistics insight here?

Here's my code:

```
def single_experiment(p, n):
    return [random.random() < p for i in range(n)]

def run(experiments, bet_success_rate):
    random.seed(datetime.now())
    num_bets_in_exp = 20
    pval_threshold = 0.02
    noisy_exp = 0

    success_chances = {}
    bets = {}
    stats = []
    pvals = []
    for _ in tqdm(range(experiments)):
        exp = single_experiment(bet_success_rate, num_bets_in_exp)
        res = binomtest(sum(exp), num_bets_in_exp, p=bet_success_rate, alternative="greater")
        pval = res.pvalue
        if pval < pval_threshold:
            noisy_exp += 1

    print(noisy_exp / experiments)
```

And here's a screenshot with the results:[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ...  am I missing some statistics insight here?

Yes, but you're not the first, and you won't be the last.

Your expectation is based on the behavior of a statistical test whose underlying probability distribution is *continuous*.  When the distribution is continuous, under the null hypothesis the distribution of the p-values is uniform, and your expectation for the ratio of the counts would be correct.

The binomial test is based on the binomial distribution, which is a *discrete* distribution.   The [probability mass function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_mass_function) (PMF) of the distribution with `n = 20` and `p = 0.1` is shown in the following plot:

[image: plot of pmf]

Suppose in one experiment we observe `k = 4`.  The binomial test with `alternative='greater'` asks: given that the observation is from the binomial distribution with `n = 20` and `p = 0.1`, what is the probability that we would observe the value 4 or larger in an experiment?  If we use `scipy.stats.binomtest`, we get:

```
In [40]: from scipy.stats import binomtest, binom

In [41]: n = 20
In [42]: p = 0.1

In [43]: binomtest(4, n, p, alternative='greater').pvalue
Out[43]: 0.1329533234343351
```

Note that this is simply the sum of the PMF values for k = 4, 5, ..., 20 (`binom.pmf` is the implementation of the binomial PMF):

```
In [46]: binom.pmf(np.arange(4, n+1), n, p).sum()
Out[46]: 0.13295332343433505
```

We can use the [*survival function*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Survival_function) of the binomial distribution (implemented as `scipy.stats.binom.sf`) to compute this sum.  We have to subtract one from the argument, because `binom.sf(k, n, p)` sums the PMF from k+1 to the end, and we want to include `k`:

```
In [47]: binom.sf(4-1, n, p)
Out[47]: 0.1329533234343351
```

Knowing this, we can compute all the possible p-values that can be produced by the binomial test for a given `n` and `p`:

```
In [51]: for i in range(n + 1):
    ...:     print(f'{i:3}  {binom.sf(i-1, n, p):<9.4g}')
    ...: 
  0  1        
  1  0.8784   
  2  0.6083   
  3  0.3231   
  4  0.133    
  5  0.04317  
  6  0.01125  
  7  0.002386 
  8  0.0004156
  9  5.986e-05
 10  7.151e-06
 11  7.089e-07
 12  5.815e-08
 13  3.923e-09
 14  2.155e-10
 15  9.481e-12
 16  3.263e-13
 17  8.466e-15
 18  1.557e-16
 19  1.81e-18 
 20  1e-20
```

In your code, you counted all the experiments where the p-value was less than 0.02.  Given the discrete set of possible p-values shown above, you can see that this will be the same as counting all the experiments where the p-values were less than or equal to 0.01125, and that is the ratio you should expect to observe if the number of experiments is large. I just tried 1000000 experiments, and got a ratio of 0.011239.

If you increase the threshold to something greater than 0.04317 but less than 0.133, the ratio should be approximately 0.04317.  For example, in a run with a threshold of 0.05 and 1000000 experiments, I got 0.04319 for the ratio.